# Python Operator Overloading confusion

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading

Please can someone provide some clarity on this python tutorial i have watched:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqF_r0FDgEc&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYt4e0WnBp-ZjCNq8X0FX0J&index=54

Around the 16 minute mark he's talking about using in built `__str__()` method. I
wanted to know the purpose of this method. Why would i use this instead of simply
creating my own method with a more meaningful name, for instance `circle_area()`.

The only difference i can see is instead of being able to call it like this:

```
circle_area(c1)
```

I would have to call it like this:

```
c1.circle_area()
```

Also the main part of the tutorial is explaining the use of in built methods like `__add__`.

Instead of using that method i could instead do this to create c3:

`c3 = Circle(c1.__radius + c2.__radius)`

instead of this:

c3 = c1 + c2

I don't see the point of the in built methods he has mentioned. Is the only reason for using them because it would make programs look slightly neater?

Comment: `__str__` is called when you `print` an object, and the name is perfectly meaningful, as the method returns a string that represents it.

Answer (score -1):

Overloading a method allows you to define it for your specific use case of the objects.

If you overload `__add__`, you can use `c1 + c2` instead of `c1.__radius + c2.__radius`.

The purpose? Neatness and abstraction. I'd definitely like c1 + c2 to work in my program. I'm adding two circle objects, I expect to get their radius added!

The video overloads and uses `__str__` to print **circle area =**.
This same behaviour can be obtained with:

```
print("Circle area =", c1.area() )
```

The goal is to achieve abstraction instead of calling area method every time and printing the same thing.

May seem pointless when all you have is 20 lines of code, makes sense in a reality.

Overloading is definitely helpful in larger projects, and would seem a hassle in tiny ones. Tutorials are mostly tiny!

Comment: Addition between objects usually doesn't make any sense - that's the case here, the example from the tutorial is poorly chosen, as there is no notion of 'adding circles' in geometry. Defining a proper `__str__` method in order to get meaningful information when printing an object is, on the other side, very common and a good practice.